# Cordova plugin's JS files not being copied to platforms/ folder

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

We have a project which has some custom plugins. The problem is that when I do

```
cordova build ios
```

then the plugins' JS files are not copied over to *platforms/ios/www/plugins/*, even though the build succeeds without any errors but when I try to install/run the application, then I get undefined error if I access `window.plugins`.

Furthermore, the *ios.json* file in platforms/ios/ doesn't have any entries for the plugins, it is like empty:

```
{
    "prepare_queue": {
        "installed": [],
        "uninstalled": []
    },
    "config_munge": {
        "files": {}
    },
    "installed_plugins": {},
    "dependent_plugins": {}
}
```

If I do `cordova plugin list`, I can see the list of all the plugins in there. Also the plugins' .h and .m files are copied and present in *platforms/ios//Plugins/*

These are the contents of my config.xml file.

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.myapp.enterprise.prod" version="0.0.50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <name>MyApp</name>
        <description>
            A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
        </description>
        <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
            Apache Cordova Team
        </author>
        <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
        -->
        <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
        <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
        <!-- <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.4.0" /> -->
        <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
        <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
        <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
        <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
        <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
        <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
        <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
        <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
        <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
        <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
        <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
        <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
        <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
        <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
        <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
        <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
        <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
        <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
        <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
        <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
        <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
        <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
        <preference name="fadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1" />
        <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash_je" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
    </widget>
```

Also there is no cordova_plugins.js file in the platforms/ios/ folder.

I'm using Mac OS X (El Capitan), Cordova v5.4.0, Xcode v7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9976) with iOS plugins in Cordova 5.4.0. Try downgrading Cordova `npm install -g cordova@5.3.3` or removing and reinstalling your plugin(s) to the project.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That worked. I couldn't upvote your answer due to no rep. Anyways, really appreciate that. I was struggling with it for two days.

Comment: I believe this has been fixed in Cordova 5.4.1.  Also make sure your plugins are saved to the config.xml which you can do with `cordova plugin save`.